# Counting distinct members based on number of months in duration of time

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a membership table with the following columns:

```
Member_number  | StartDate   | EndDate
XYZ            | 01-Jan-2002 | 01-March-2002 
ABC            | 01-Feb-2002 | 01-March-2002
```

Basically, I want to show how many members were present in specific month. My problem is I don't know how to break this time span into months.  How can I see this result?

```
Month  |  NumberOfMembers
Jan    |  1
Feb    |  2
March  |  2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given a members table that looks something like this:

```
create table dbo.members
(
  member_number int      not null primary key ,
  start_date    datetime not null ,
  end_date      datetime not null ,
)
```

And a table-valued function that generates sequences of consecutive integers, like this:

```
create function dbo.IntegerRange ( @from int , @thru int )
returns @sequence table
(
  value int not null primary key clustered
)
as
begin

  declare @increment int = case when @from > @thru then -1 else 1 end ;

  with sequence(value) as
  (
      select value = @from
    union all
      select value + @increment
      from sequence
      where value < @thru
  )
  insert @sequence
  select value
  from sequence
  order by value
  option ( MAXRECURSION 0 )

  return

end
```

A query like this should give you what you want:

```
select [year]     = period.yyyy ,
       [month]    = case period.mm ,
                    when  1 then 'Jan'
                    when  2 then 'Feb'
                    when  3 then 'Mar'
                    when  4 then 'Apr'
                    when  5 then 'May'
                    when  6 then 'Jun'
                    when  7 then 'Jul'
                    when  8 then 'Aug'
                    when  9 then 'Sep'
                    when 10 then 'Oct'
                    when 11 then 'Nov'
                    when 12 then 'Dev'
                    else         '***'
                    end ,
       member_cnt = sum( case when m.member_number is not null then 1 else 0 end )
from ( select yyyy   = yyyy.value ,
              mm     = mm.value ,
              dtFrom = dateadd( month , mm.value - 1 , dateadd( year , yyyy.value - 1900 , convert(date,'') ) ) ,
              dtThru = dateadd( day , - 1 , dateadd( month , mm.value     , dateadd( year , yyyy.value - 1900 , convert(date,'') ) ) )
       from      dbo.IntegerRange(2000,2013) yyyy
       full join dbo.IntegerRange(1,12)      mm   on 1=1
     ) period
left join dbo.members m on period.dtFrom <= m.end_date
                       and period.dtThru >= m.start_date
group by period.yyyy ,
         period.mm
order by period.yyyy ,
         period.mm
```

The first table expression in the `from` clause creates a virtual table of the periods (months, in this case, but the technique doesn't limit itself to months or even weeks) covering the reporting period:

```
from ( select yyyy   = yyyy.value ,
              mm     = mm.value ,
              dtFrom = dateadd( month , mm.value - 1 , dateadd( year , yyyy.value - 1900 , convert(date,'') ) ) ,
              dtThru = dateadd( day , - 1 , dateadd( month , mm.value     , dateadd( year , yyyy.value - 1900 , convert(date,'') ) ) )
       from      dbo.IntegerRange(2000,2013) yyyy
       full join dbo.IntegerRange(1,12)      mm   on 1=1
     ) period
```

That is then joined, via a `left outer join`, ensuring that *all* periods are reported, not just those periods with active members, to the members table to collect, for each reporting period in the virtual `period` table above, the set of members who were active during the period:

```
left join dbo.members m on period.dtFrom <= m.end_date
                       and period.dtThru >= m.start_date
```

We then group by the year and month of each period and then order the results by year/month number:

```
group by period.yyyy ,
         period.mm
order by period.yyyy ,
         period.mm
```

In creating the results set to be returned, we return the year of the period, the month number (converted to a friendly name), and the count of active members. Note that we have to use the `sum()` aggregate function here rather than `count()` as empty periods will have a single row returned (with `null` in all columns). `Count()`, unlike all other aggregate functions, includes `null` values in the aggregation. `Sum()` is applied to a case expression acting as a discriminant function returning 1 or 0 identifying whether the row indicates useful or missing data:

```
select [year]     = period.yyyy ,
       [month]    = case period.mm ,
                    when  1 then 'Jan'
                    when  2 then 'Feb'
                    when  3 then 'Mar'
                    when  4 then 'Apr'
                    when  5 then 'May'
                    when  6 then 'Jun'
                    when  7 then 'Jul'
                    when  8 then 'Aug'
                    when  9 then 'Sep'
                    when 10 then 'Oct'
                    when 11 then 'Nov'
                    when 12 then 'Dev'
                    else         '***'
                    end ,
       member_cnt = sum( case when m.member_number is not null then 1 else 0 end )
```

Easy!

Comment: @galuano1 -- ?? 'Terse' is not an adjective anybody would ever claim for SQL. FWIW, a table-valued function or a table capable of generating large sequences of values comes in quite useful in writing SQL, especially in the domain of reports. Let you flesh out sparse data as required.

Answer (score 1):

```
DECLARE @minMonth DATE
SELECT @minMonth = MIN(StartDate) FROM Table1

DECLARE @maxMonth DATE
SELECT @maxMonth = MAX(EndDate) FROM Table1


;WITH CTE_Months AS
(
    SELECT @minMonth AS Mnth
    UNION ALL
    SELECT DATEADD(MM,1,Mnth) FROM  CTE_Months
    WHERE Mnth<@MaxMonth
)
SELECT Mnth AS Month, COUNT(*) as Members
FROM CTE_Months m
LEFT JOIN Table1 t on m.Mnth BETWEEN t.StartDate AND t.EndDate
GROUP BY Mnth
```

**[SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/3222b/2)**

CTE will find all months from min StartDate to max EndDate, if you need different min and max, just change how you get @MinMonth and @MaxMonth

If you don't want to show zeros for months that possibly don't have any members, replace LEFT JOIN with INNER at the end.

Answer (score 0):

```
select t.Month, count(*) Members
from (
  select case  
    when startdate <= to_date('01-Jan-2002', 'DD-MON-YYYY') AND enddate >= to_date('31-Jan-2002', 'DD-MON-YYYY') then ' Jan'
    when startdate <= to_date('01-Feb-2002', 'DD-MON-YYYY') AND enddate >= to_date('28-Feb-2002', 'DD-MON-YYYY') then ' Feb'
    when startdate <= to_date('01-Mar-2002', 'DD-MON-YYYY') AND enddate >= to_date('31-Mar-2002', 'DD-MON-YYYY') then ' Mar'
    when startdate <= to_date('01-Apr-2002', 'DD-MON-YYYY') AND enddate >= to_date('30-Apr-2002', 'DD-MON-YYYY') then ' Apr'
    when startdate <= to_date('01-May-2002', 'DD-MON-YYYY') AND enddate >= to_date('31-May-2002', 'DD-MON-YYYY') then ' May'
    when startdate <= to_date('01-Jun-2002', 'DD-MON-YYYY') AND enddate >= to_date('30-Jun-2002', 'DD-MON-YYYY') then ' Jun'
    when startdate <= to_date('01-Jul-2002', 'DD-MON-YYYY') AND enddate >= to_date('31-Jul-2002', 'DD-MON-YYYY') then ' Jul'
    when startdate <= to_date('01-Aug-2002', 'DD-MON-YYYY') AND enddate >= to_date('31-Aug-2002', 'DD-MON-YYYY') then ' Aug'
    when startdate <= to_date('01-Sep-2002', 'DD-MON-YYYY') AND enddate >= to_date('30-Sep-2002', 'DD-MON-YYYY') then ' Sep'
    when startdate <= to_date('01-Oct-2002', 'DD-MON-YYYY') AND enddate >= to_date('31-Oct-2002', 'DD-MON-YYYY') then ' Oct'
    when startdate <= to_date('01-Nov-2002', 'DD-MON-YYYY') AND enddate >= to_date('30-Nov-2002', 'DD-MON-YYYY') then ' Nov'
    when startdate <= to_date('01-Dec-2002', 'DD-MON-YYYY') AND enddate >= to_date('31-Dec-2002', 'DD-MON-YYYY') then ' Dec'
  end as Month
from member) t
group by t.Month
```

Where `member` is the table name.

Comment: He wants to return the counts *by month*.

Comment: This will be true only for year 2002.